# Problems with Intel-Undervolting

Tags: 18.04

I had some major  problems a couple of days ago. I tested both intel-undervolt and iuvolt and my laptop got all laggy and stuff. I then deleted and uninstalled iuvolt and also deleted msr tools thinking that this will reset any undervolts on the cpu. Today my laptop is great however i cannot seem to be able to remove intel-undervolt from the system and then reinstall msr tools. Eventually I just want to have intel-undervolt but right now it says msr tools not found when I run it from terminal. Any tips on how to reinstall msr tools,remove inte-undervolt and reinstall it. Thanks

Comment: How are you "removing" intel-undervolt, and what is the output of the removal?

Comment: @j-money I am trying sudo apt-get remove intel-undervolt and i get E: Unable to locatr package intel-undervolt.  However on a new terminal if I type intel-undervolt I get all the menu options.

Comment: can you `which intel-undervolt`? Also you might try to "install" intel-undervolt `sudo apt-get install -f intel-undervolt` and then try removing it

Comment: @j-money Same thing on both i get unable to locate intel undervolt.
EDIT: ON which intel-undervolt i now get /usr/bin/intel-undervolt

Comment: output of `sudo apt-get install -f intel-undervolt`

Comment: @j-money Output is :
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package intel-undervot

Comment: make sure you spell it correctly.. `sudo apt-get install -f intel-undervot` **!=** `sudo apt-get install -f intel-undervot`